# How to describe and sketch a function $y^2-z^2=25$ in a 3D space?

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces

> The function given to me is $y^2-z^2=25$. I am required to describe the graph of this function in space, and then required to plot it.

Trail:

Finding trace of the given surface on coordinate planes. On the $xy$ plane $z=0$ I get a line. On the $yz$ plane I get an equation of the form $x=\sqrt{z^2+25}$ two values negative and positive. what will be this trace? On the $zx$ plane a line again. How do I combine this interpret this information and combine it to graph the given function in space.

The graph of this function using Maple shows that, it never touches $xz$ coordinate plane and the graph looks like parabolic sheet opening towards $y$ axis.

Can someone please explain how to first collect the information from the given equation and then graph it in a space and then define the shape in space (one of the type of quadratic surface).

Comment: Where does your $x$ come from? The equation only contains $y$ and $z$, so I would consider it to lie in the $yz$ plane. In fact, every altering of $x$ will give the same function, so if you understand the function in the $yz$ plane, you just pull this into a 3D-figure along the $x$ axis, if you really need three dimensions. However, I don't understand why you do computations involving $x$, this should be the last step, not the first one...

Comment: It is represented by a **hyperbolic cylinder** (vertical sections parallel to $yz$ plane, whatever $x$, are hyperbolas with the given equation).

Comment: @Bemte, yes you are correct. The equation on the $yz$ plane is hyperbola. Now the part extend it to $x$ to get 3D figure I am unable to comprehend. Can you please elaborate on this.

Comment: @JeanMarie, Yes indeed its a hyperbolic cylinder. Can I safely say, its not a hyperboloid and hyperbolic paraboloid because one variable is missing?

Comment: No, that's not the explanation. It is an hyperbolic cylinder because it is generated in two steps: first by building a hyperbola ("standard" equation $(y/5)^2-(z/5)^2=1$) in the $yz$ plane, then by translating this "template" along a direction which does not belong to the original $yz$ plane (each point generating thus a "generatrix" of the cylinder), this direction being given here by the $x$ axis.

Comment: If you know the form on the $yz$ plane, you are almost done. For a simpler example, take $y^2 + z^2 = 1$. Then you would have a circle on the $yz$ plane. Furthermore, for every $x$ you would have the same circle, as the equation does not depend on $x$. So for every $x$, you draw exactly the same circle, at the same position. What comes out will be an (infinite) cylinder. Maybe try to just plot a circle on a paper and ask yourself what happens if you extend it in this way to a 3D-figure.

Comment: I think I have fairly understood the idea now. Thank a lot brothers.